# How to submit form every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't find right syntax. How to submit form (or imitate click on submit button) every 10 seconds? The page doesn't reload, so I need a loop.

Comment: DOM, setInterval, AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting your own page, there's no need to do a real form post, as it reloads the page. Use an Interval with Ajax calls.

It sounds like, however, that you're re-posting someone else's page.

For demonstration, here's what your target page might look like:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="name" value="123">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When the form is posted, the following fields are sent to the server. What you do here, is to emulate that page with your own page, but with a twist:

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
  <input name="name" value="123">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
</script>
```

Call the above page poster.htm. Now embed it in an iframe, dynamically:

```
<iframe id="autopost"></iframe>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
  if (!document.version) document.version=1;
  document.version++;
  document.getElementById('autopost').src='poster.htm?v='+document.version;
},10000);
</script>
```

The version number is there to prevent caching.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 setInterval("$('form').submit()",10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout()` and an `$.ajax()` call to do the submit itself.

You can avoid the `$.ajax()` call if the submit returns to the same form.